# How to set the facecolor of a plot for saved figures

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am working with some code that uses `matplotlib v.3.1.2` on Docker (**I can't change this**), and I can't figure out how to set the background color of my saved plots to a different color than white (while keeping the `fig` background white).

Looking for a solution, I found three different approaches -- but none of them work.

Method 1 (changes the background color of both `fig` and `axis` to azure):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axis = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, facecolor='azure')
for ax in axis:
    ...

...

plt.savefig(..., facecolor=fig.get_facecolor(), transparent=True)
```

Method 2 (doesn't do anything, i.e., the background color of both `fig` and `axis` remains white):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axis = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1)
for ax in axis:
    ...
    ax.set_facecolor('azure')

...

plt.savefig(..., facecolor=fig.get_facecolor(), transparent=True)
```

Method 3 (same result as Method 2):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['axes.facecolor'] = 'azure'

fig, axis = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1)
for ax in axis:
    ...

...

plt.savefig(..., facecolor=fig.get_facecolor(), transparent=True)
```

What am I doing wrong?

### Here is the complete test example

```
import os
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.rcParams['font.serif'] = 'Rockwell'
plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'serif'

BACKGROUND_COLOR = (1, 1, 1)
FONT_COLOR = (0.1, 0.1, 0.1)
MY_PATH = ...

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1)

vals = [[random.uniform(1.0, 8.0) for i in range(10)], 
        [random.uniform(1.0, 8.0) for i in range(10)]]
x = [i for i in range(10)]

colors = ['#F15854', '#B276B2']
legends = ['Feature 1', 'Feature 2']
for (colr, leg, y) in zip(colors, legends, vals):
    for i in [0, 1]:
        axes[i].plot(x, y, label=leg, linewidth=2, color=colr, alpha=1)

frm_min = int(x[0])
frm_max = int(x[-1])
for ax in axes:
    range_x = np.arange(frm_min, frm_max + 1, 2)
    ax.set_xticks(range_x)
    ax.set_xticklabels(range_x, fontsize=10)
    range_y = range(0, 8, 1)
    ax.set_yticks(range_y)
    ax.set_yticklabels(range_y, fontsize=10)
    ax.set_xlim(frm_min, frm_max)
    ax.grid(which='major', axis='x', linestyle=':')
    ax.set_xlabel('Time (s)')
    ax.set_ylabel('Value')

    main_legend = ax.legend(loc=7, ncol=1, borderaxespad=-10.0, fontsize=16)
    main_frame = main_legend.get_frame()
    main_frame.set_facecolor(BACKGROUND_COLOR)
    main_frame.set_edgecolor(BACKGROUND_COLOR)
    for text in main_legend.get_texts():
        text.set_color(FONT_COLOR)

    ax.set_facecolor('azure')

fig.suptitle('Figure title', fontsize=24, ha='center', color=FONT_COLOR)
fig.tight_layout(rect=[0, 0, 0.925, 0.925])  

plt.show()
plt.savefig(
    os.path.join(MY_PATH, 'filename.png'),
    bbox_inches='tight',
    dpi=300,
    facecolor=fig.get_facecolor(),
    transparent=True,
)
plt.close(fig)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution turned out to be very simple: I had to change `transparent` in `savefig()` to `False`. Now, all three methods as described in my original post do as they are expected to. Case closed!